# How do I change UIImageView opacity based on proximity to location (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have set up a custom object defining "MyLocation" which is used in an array to show the name of the nearest location and the distance between the user location and the nearest location.

Essentially I want the opacity of the 'imageView' to change depending on the .distance value of 'MyLocation'.

All the images are added before hand in a subview and I am just making them visible by changing the opacity when the user enters a region.

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

    if  region.identifier == "Home" {

        FirstLocationImg.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {
            self.FirstLocationImg.alpha = 1
        }
    }

    if locationsArray.first!.distance < 50 {
        imageView.alpha = locationsArray.first!.distance
    }
}
```

I think the code I have is mostly there, but I get the issue of

"Cannot assign value of type 'Double!' to type 'CGFloat'."

here is my custom object:

```
class MyLocation {

var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var distance: Double!
var regionDistance: Double!
var identifier: String!


var region: CLCircularRegion  {
    return CLCircularRegion(center: coord, radius: regionDistance, identifier: identifier)
}

init(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, regionDistance: Double, identifier: String) {
    self.coord = coord
    self.regionDistance = regionDistance
    self.identifier = identifier
}

}
```

Is my method correct? or is there a better way to go about this?

So stuck!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I see that I cannot assign a number or more than 1 to the alpha value of the image. So it seem I need to find a way to convert the numbers (from 1-50) which I will be getting from the distance to a range of 0-1. e.g. If I use increments of 2 Meters to represent 0.1 on the alpha scale?

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: `alpha` is `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the Issue:

using 
    CGFloat(locationsArray.first!.distance)

and then dividing the number I have for the distance between 2 points to get a number between 0 and 1.